# Scrape text from html element by class that's inside a list element

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the headline from the first h4 element with the class "regularitem".
The output should look like "`It took months to hit 3 million reported cases...`"
I keep getting list index out of range.

```
 headers = {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
                }

            URL = 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss'

            req = requests.get(URL, headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
            headline = soup.findAll('h4', attrs = {'class' : 'itemtitle'})[0]
            print(headline.get_text)
```

The page html looks like this:

```
<li xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" class="regularitem">
<h4 class="itemtitle"><a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~3/3M8R-V8mvn8/index.html">It took months to hit 3 million reported cases. Now nearly two weeks later, US is on the verge of 4 million.</a></h4>
<h5 class="itemposttime">
<span>Posted:</span>Wed, 22 Jul 2020 14:52:09 GMT</h5>
<div class="itemcontent" name="decodeable">Tracking US cases | Podcast | Those you've lost<div class="feedflare">
<a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=3M8R-V8mvn8:YP_46RpyuXw:yIl2AUoC8zA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=3M8R-V8mvn8:YP_46RpyuXw:7Q72WNTAKBA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=7Q72WNTAKBA" border="0"></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=3M8R-V8mvn8:YP_46RpyuXw:V_sGLiPBpWU"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?i=3M8R-V8mvn8:YP_46RpyuXw:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=3M8R-V8mvn8:YP_46RpyuXw:qj6IDK7rITs"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0"></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=3M8R-V8mvn8:YP_46RpyuXw:gIN9vFwOqvQ"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?i=3M8R-V8mvn8:YP_46RpyuXw:gIN9vFwOqvQ" border="0"></a>
</div><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~4/3M8R-V8mvn8" height="1" width="1" alt=""></div>
</li>
<li xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" class="regularitem">
<h4 class="itemtitle"><a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~3/e93U4xIXAew/h_b91e6cf9dac712028ccce8edf19ff634">'We are going as quickly as we possibly can' on vaccine development, Fauci says</a></h4>
<h5 class="itemposttime"></h5>
<div class="itemcontent" name="decodeable"><div class="feedflare">
<a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=e93U4xIXAew:NWKJndB2i28:yIl2AUoC8zA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=e93U4xIXAew:NWKJndB2i28:7Q72WNTAKBA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=7Q72WNTAKBA" border="0"></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=e93U4xIXAew:NWKJndB2i28:V_sGLiPBpWU"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?i=e93U4xIXAew:NWKJndB2i28:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=e93U4xIXAew:NWKJndB2i28:qj6IDK7rITs"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0"></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=e93U4xIXAew:NWKJndB2i28:gIN9vFwOqvQ"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?i=e93U4xIXAew:NWKJndB2i28:gIN9vFwOqvQ" border="0"></a>
</div><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~4/e93U4xIXAew" height="1" width="1" alt=""></div>
</li>
```

I've tried removing the list index and changing to soup.find (see the example below) but when I do that I get: "`NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text`"

```
 headers = {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
                }

            URL = 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss'

            req = requests.get(URL, headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
            headline = soup.find('h4', attrs = {'class' : 'itemtitle'})
            print(headline.get_text)
```

Comment: If you do a simple test by printing req.content you will see that the request is not actually getting the page html - so when you are using beautiful soup to parse the req.content the h4 element and <a> element within it are not present.

Comment: This may be because the content is dynamically loaded and therefore you would need to use a library like Selenium to retrieve the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request you are making is not pulling the html because the html on the page is dynamically loaded. The solution is to use selenium since selenium emulates a real browser and will load the dynamic content.

```
# these settings may differ based on where you install your chrome webdriver
# alternatively you can use the firefox webdrive - there are plenty of tutorials online that show
# you how to install those
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') # or '-start maximized' if you want to see the window open
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
}

URL = 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss'

driver.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
headlines = soup.findAll('h4', {'class': 'itemtitle'})
for headline in headlines:
    headlineText = headline.find('a').text
    print(headlineText)
```

Let me know if this was helpful

Comment: This is great and works well. However, I I'm unable to hide the browser for some reason and the argument you posted doesn't seem to work. Neither does passing ```options.headless = True``` as a parameter. Also, for others who find this, I had to add the path to my chromedriver like this: ```driver = webdriver.Chrome('path to driver', chrome_options=options)```

Comment: Not sure if this will change anything but try with just one dash (-headless) or no dashes (headless)

Comment: --headless works for me so I am not sure why this wouldn't work.